# React router V4 doesn't works

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Since 3 days i am working on react route but its not working..I
    I dont know where i am doing wrong even simple route is not working...if simple routing(without params) work then i wanted to pass ID to the NEW component..
    But i am able to pass ID optionally ..IF i remove ? then routing doesnt works.. I have tried using switch and exact too..

```
And One More issue is by passing ID optionally i am getting Undefined in New Component Page During render (First time)..So i wanted to pass ID:1 from router .Please help me out...Thanks

    <Route name="ideas" path="/Hello" component={New} />  (Not Working)
<Route name="ideas" path="/:Hello" component={New} /> (Not working)
   <Route name="ideas" path="/New/:Hello?" component={New} />(Not working)
    <Route name="ideas" path="/" component={New} /> {Working}
    <Route name="ideas" path="/:Hello?" component={New} /> (working)

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from'react-dom'
import New from './New'
import Demo from "./demo";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Switch,

} from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
    return (
<div>
    <Router>
        <Route name="ideas" path="/Hello" component={New} />
    </Router>
</div>

);
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you add a codesandbox link. Where I can reproduce it and fix it. I think yo are missing **exact**.

Comment: Put the **exact** keyword in the home route

Comment: Here https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-surf-d0xeg is my code..@SandipNirmal

Comment: @IbrahimHasnat Sorry i didnt work i tried that too..You can see attached CodesandBox..Thanks

Comment: @Dodiyarutu, will check your codesandbox. I created basic example https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-currying-8job8. You can check

Comment: Hi @Dodiyarutu, Please try this repository only for router and template integration. [https://github.com/senthilmca90/react-bootstrap-template](https://github.com/senthilmca90/react-bootstrap-template). I thing useful for initial learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your codesandbox. You were not using `Switch` from `react-router-dom`. Which is necessary when dealing wit routes. Please check updated codesandbox.

Use it in following way

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import New from "./New";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route name="ideas" path="/Hello" component={New} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

You can also have a look at https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-currying-8job8.

Updated version of your code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-hellman-2f19h

Comment: nope It didnt work..May be i have some issues in webpack.config file Could you tell me how to resolve that??

Comment: Is it working on Codesandbox? You don't need any separate config if you have created it using `create-react-app`.

Comment: nope its not working in codesandbox even..If i add path="/:Home?" its working well..otherwise its not working...